# This object inside promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I think there are questions similar to this one, but not exactly answering what I want.

In the specification for [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) 25.4.5.1 it states:

> When the **catch** method is called with arguments *onRejected*, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let promise be the **this** value

Does that means that in the catch method of a promise **this** should resolve to the promise?

If I do:

```
Promise.reject(1).catch(function (res) {console.log(this)})
```

the global object is logged, both in chrome and in Node 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not what it means.

> When the **`catch`** method is called with argument *onRejected*, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *promise* be the **this** value.
> 2. Return ? Invoke(*promise*, "then", « **undefined**, *onRejected* »).

This just declares the definition of `promise.catch`, which is:

```js
Promise.prototype.catch = function(onRejected) {
  // Let promise be the this value.
  var promise = this;

  // Return ? Invoke(promise, "then", « undefined, onRejected »).
  return promise.then(undefined, onRejected);
}
```

So calling `promise.catch(onRejected)` is equivalent to calling
`promise.then(undefined, onRejected)`.